# Counting table rows in WebdriverIO

Tags: arrays, node.js, webdriver-io

I am testing a webshop with a dynamical webtable that can contain anywhere from 0 to 100 rows (orders). I am forced to use NodeJS and WebdriverIO for this, both very new for me.

I want to delete every order that has 'Open'status. I am used to working with Java, where I would just add all applicable webelements to an array, and then put the delete command in a loop that would run for as many times as the array is long.

I managed to create the needed loop like this (open orders are always on top, loop is allowd to break as soon as it encounters a non open order:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) { 
      var orderStatus = browser.getText("//*[@class='jum-order-list-table-b2c']//tr[1]//*[@class='jum-status']/div[2]/span")
      console.log(orderStatus)
      if (orderStatus != 'Open') { break; } 
        browser.pause(1000)
        browser.click("//*[@class='jum-order-list-table-b2c']//tr[1]//*[@class='jum-list-actions']/div/a")
        browser.pause(1000)
        browser.click("//*[@value='Bestelling annuleren']")
        browser.pause(1000)
        browser.click("//*[@class='ui-dialog-buttonset']//button[2]")
        browser.pause(1000)
```

but I can't figure out how to make an array of webelements.

I managed to come up with this:

```
var orderTable = browser.getText("//*[@class='jum-order-list-table-b2c']//*[@class='jum-order-number']/div[2]")
```

But this only creates an array when there are more then 1 elements. I also want it to be an array when there are no, or just 1 webelements

Can anyone tell be how I can achieve this?

The part of the site I am working with looks like this:

```
<tbody>
  <tr class="jum-open-order-row">
    <td class="jum-order-type jum-ga-b2b-bestellingen-orderdata">
    <td class="jum-cell-bold">
    <td class="jum-order-number">
    <td class="jum-status">
    <td class="jum-price">
    <td class="jum-list-actions">
  </tr>
  <tr class="jum-open-order-row">
  <tr class="jum-open-order-row">
  <tr class="jum-open-order-row">
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have more experience with CSS Selectors than XPath, however, there is the `browser.elements` method. This returns 1 or many elements matching a particular selector.

http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/elements.html

You can shorthand `browser.elements` to be `browser.$$` if you want too.

Then Use `elementIdText` to pull the element's text value for "Open" orders

http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/elementIdText.html#Usage

The returned response is an array of results corresponding to rows of orders and it's status `<td>`

```
let openOrderRowStatuses = browser.elements('.jum-open-order-row .jum-status')
```

Now that we have an array of "open orders statuses" lets get the text values of these statuses.

```
//Let's forEach every returned JSON WebElement and get the Text of the Status... 
openOrderRowStatuses.forEach((elem, index)) => {
   //Get the Text Value with `elementIdText' elem.value.ELEMENT 
   let orderStatus = browser.elementIdText(elem.value.ELEMENT)
   if(orderStatus === "Open"){
      //Perform Delete Logic
   }
}
```

I'm sure you might have to tinker with your exact setup and selectors, but this is one way of working with an array of elements yielded success for me. I am using ES6 Syntax, so you might have to adapt your solution. But the "Index" value is passed with the forEach loop so you have reference to which row you're working with.

Hope this helps!